# C++ 5 dimensional vector?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, programming-languages, vector

I am trying to make a 5 dimensional vector and I can’t seem to get it to work. 
I know if I need to write a 3 dimensional vector, I could write it in the following way: 
`vector< vector< vector<string> > > block(27, vector< vector<string> > (27, vector<string>(27)));`

Then I call it:  `block[x][y][z] = “hello”;`

I wrote the 5 dimensional vector in the following way and it gives me error.
`vector< vector< vector< vector< vector<string> > > > > block(27, vector< vector< vector< vector<string> > > >(27, vector< vector< vector<string> > >(27, vector< vector<string> >(27, vector<string>(27)))));`

Can you please tell me how to write a 5 dimensional vector in the right way? 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is it `c++`? The last vector must be `std::vector<int>`, for example, or `std::vector<std::string>` or something like this. What error does compiler give?

Comment: Did you consider using a library? How about Boost.MultiArray?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But you should stop and think if a dictionary would work better. If the data is sparse you'll save a ton of memory.
Create a key using the 5 dimensions, and create only the members you need.

Comment: Thanks, maps did the job just fine without messing with my memory too much. and essay use.

Answer (score 6):

The final vector in your 5 dimensional array does not have a type that it is an array of.

```
vector< vector< vector< vector< vector > > > > 
                                     ^^
                                     Here. What is the base vector a vector off?
```

To make things easy to read a couple of typedefs would be nice:

```
typedef std::vector<std::string>     Dim1;
typedef std::vector<Dim1>            Dim2;
typedef std::vector<Dim2>            Dim3;
typedef std::vector<Dim3>            Dim4;
typedef std::vector<Dim4>            Dim5;

Dim5 block(27, Dim4(27, Dim3(27, Dim2(27, Dim1(27)))));
```

Comment: I want to make that 5D array hold a value in the following format. 
block[1][1][1][1][1]= "hello";
My 3 dimensional array works just fine the way I wrote it above. could you please rewrite the above 5 dimensional array the way it should be? Thanks.

Comment: ok, thanks a lot. didn't see your full message earlier. that helps a lot. Thanks.

Comment: oops, I still have the same problem. what you wrote works just like mine. it gives me lots of warnings first. then program runs and it wouldn't go pass the point where you declare the vector. memory keeps building up and crash. it gave the fallowing long warning. 

warning C4503: 'std::vector<_Ty>::vector' : decorated name length exceeded, name was truncated
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=Dim4
1>        ]
1>: warning C4503: 'std::vector<_Ty>::_Construct_n' : decorated name length exceeded, name was truncated
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=Dim4
1>        ]
.
.
.
.

Answer (score 6):

Consider using the Boost Multidimensional Array Library for higher dimensional arrays.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html

"Boost MultiArray is a more efficient and convenient way to express N-dimensional arrays than existing alternatives (especially the std::vector> formulation of N-dimensional arrays). The arrays provided by the library may be accessed using the familiar syntax of native C++ arrays. Additional features, such as resizing, reshaping, and creating views are available (and described below)."